# Is it possible to improve the compilation speed of a large Sass file without splitting it?

Tags: sass, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a Sass file with 60,000 lines, all using placeholders (%) for inheritance. However, in development mode, each update has a delay of 4 seconds.

I have tried reducing the code to 50,000 lines, but the improvement is not significant.

Is it possible to use PostCSS to only extract the required %className without compiling the entire file, without splitting the document, to improve the update speed?

Comment: use `dart-sass` it is extremely fast.